# Unity smooth camera zooming Rts game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, zooming

Hello so i have a problem my camera is really sanping and i want it to zoom in and out smooth i looked at videos and forums but i dont know how can i get help this is the code for all the camera its for a rts game and all it does for now is you can zoom in out move the camera with your mouse being on the edges on the screen.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RtsCamera : MonoBehaviour {

    public float scrollZone = 16;
    public float scrollSpeed = 5;
    public float zoomSensitivy = 15.0f;


    public float xMax = 8;
    public float xMin = 0;
    public float yMax = 8;
    public float yMin = 0;
    public float zMax = 8;
    public float zMin = 0;

    private Vector3 desiredPosition;
    private void Start()
    {
        desiredPosition = transform.position;
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

       float x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
       float speed = scrollZone * Time.deltaTime;

        if (Input.mousePosition.x < scrollZone)
            x -= speed;
        else if (Input.mousePosition.x > Screen.width - scrollZone)
            x += speed;

        if (Input.mousePosition.y < scrollZone)
            z -= speed;
        else if (Input.mousePosition.y > Screen.height - scrollZone)
            z += speed;


        y += Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel")* zoomSensitivy;

        Vector3 move = new Vector3(x,y,z) + transform.position;
        move.x = Mathf.Clamp(move.x ,xMin ,xMax);
        move.y = Mathf.Clamp(move.y ,yMin ,yMax);
        move.z = Mathf.Clamp(move.z ,zMin ,zMax);
        desiredPosition = move;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, desiredPosition, 0.2f);

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try using time.deltatime in this line?
 transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, desiredPosition, 0.2f);
Like:
 transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, desiredPosition, 2*Time.deltaTime);

Comment: @ZayedUpal thats a misuse of Lerp https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html

Comment: @yes, I've read this before, but couldn't understand, what's wrong. And this is used in so many places and works too. Can you please help me understanding, what's wrong with it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ZayedUpal its your t value that makes no sense to me (i might be mistaken though). in case of V3.Lerp think of the t value of where a point lies on a line between a and b. t is clamped between 0 and 1 and you can see at sort of a percentage. 0.5 is half way or 50%. now you interpolate by two times it took the last frame to render. assuming 60fps thats 0.0333... or 3.333%. feels kinda arbitrary to me.